# Laravel - Upload file error "PostTooLargeException"

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, mamp

I have a form that uploads two files. If I upload small files it works well but if I upload large files gives me this warning:

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 31996010 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I have read some article that tell to change the php.in `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. I change both to `200M` and restart mamp.

If I go to the phpinfo file I saw both parameters with 200M, so it changes that but the warning continuous and don't upload the files.

My code to upload is that:

```
$coverName = uniqid($catalogue->companyId.'_C'.$catalogue->ref.'_');
    $fileName = uniqid($catalogue->companyId.'_P'.$catalogue->ref.'_');
    $coverExtension = $request->file('cover')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $pdfExtension = $request->file('pdf')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destination = '/storage/app/public/uploads';

    $request->file('cover')->move($destination, $coverName.".".$coverExtension);
    $request->file('pdf')->move($destination, $fileName.".".$pdfExtension);
```

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Do I have to change some definition in laravel?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to run `php -i` and checked the correct .ini file for `Loaded Configuration File` (NOT just the `Configuration File`)

Comment: Works! Thank you @Daniel

Comment: Glad to be of help. I've added my comment as a question to it hopefully can help others with the same problem. Feel free to accept my answer :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: I faced the same problem. I tried changing the values for both settings, but still, it didn't work. Although, the changes were reflected in `phpinfo()` but, they never came in effect. Because, it turned out, when ever I was opening the `php.ini` file to edit (using `wampserver` context menu) it was opening from the `apache` directory instead of the `php` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini should solve your problem.

Make sure you're changing the correct PHP file - if you run `php -i` (which is a way to run [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) in a command line environment) you'll see both a Configuration File and a Loaded Configuration File.

Make sure you use the **Loaded Configuration File**, and not the other one.

Answer (score 1):

From the error it is clear that the max size is still set to `8M`. If your values are indeed correct in php.ini, double check that they are not being overridden somewhere else.

You should check:

- php.ini
- .htaccess
- Other apache/nginx config files

If you can't find where it is being set, you could search your system for `8M` which might locate the file in which the value is set.

EDIT: It may prove useful to dig into the [ValidatePostSize](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php) middleware where the [PostTooLargeException](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/Exceptions/PostTooLargeException.html) is thrown and attempt some debugging there.

> Do I have to change some definition in laravel?

No, you can see that the [ValidatePostSize](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php#L37) middleware compares `$request->server('CONTENT_LENGTH')` against `ini_get('post_max_size')`.

Comment: When I search for 8M shows me this in php.in... memory_limit = 128M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB) @JimWright